# How does statutory licensing under 17 USC Chapter 1 work?

Tags: copyright, recording, statutory-license

In the U.S. there is a peculiar legal framework of "compulsory statutory licensing" that applies only to commercially published "non-dramatic musical" works and audio recordings.  I'm having trouble understanding exactly what it encompasses and under what terms.

The full copyright law is in [17 USC Chapter 1](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.pdf).  It appears that statutory licensing is covered in sections 112, 114, and 115.

One [summary of this licensing regime is provided here by the entity that administers sections 112 and 114](https://www.soundexchange.com/service-provider/licensing-101/).  It appears that this license applies to "non-interactive" broadcast of commercially released recordings.  There are conditions that must be satisfied, which seem to have been designed for regional radio stations.  One term that struck me as unusual is that (if the conditions are satisfied) then the licensee only pays the statutory rate, which is [currently](https://copyright.gov/licensing/m200a.pdf) the greater of $0.091 per song or $0.0175 per minute played.  That rate applies whether it's a major radio station with hundreds of thousands of listeners or a DJ playing from his music library at a small party.  Is that correct?

And then there's [section 115](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ73.pdf), which as best I can tell:

1. Applies to the musical composition, instead of any specific recording of it.  But only after a recording of the musical composition has been sold in public?
2. Allows a licensee to make and sell recordings of the work, but not if the recordings are "intended for use in background music systems, jukeboxes, broadcasting, or any other public use."  What does that mean?  According to [this](https://www.romanolaw.com/youre-covered-when-to-obtain-a-compulsory-mechanical-license/), you can make a recording of the song and sell that recording, but this license does not allow you to publicly perform it.  So can your recording be played in public?  Are you prohibited from doing the recording in public?
3. Applies the same statutory rates as are applied under section 114, but how?  Is it per recording copy distributed?
4. Does not allow the recording to "change the basic melody or fundamental character of the work in the arrangement."  If taken at face value, this constraint seems bizarre: You can copy the work, but only if you stay sufficiently close to the *character* of the original?